# "Baudrate" or "Baud Rate"

Tags: terminology

In the context of technical writing (e.g: documentation), would it be more correct to use "*baudrate*" or "*baud rate*"?

I believe that both are acceptable informally.

However:

- I've often seen "*baudrate*" used, and previously this would be what I'd typically use.
- A quick search has yielded a preference for "*baud rate*", so I may be wrong.

Comment: the reason for putting this on hold is an answer in itself - mind = blown!

Comment: Going by mtak's answer, I don't think it is opinion... there again "_English is descriptive not prescriptive_" - it adapts to suit common usage... :-)

Comment: Beware: "baud" is **"is the number of distinct symbol changes (signaling events) made to the transmission medium per second in a digitally modulated signal or a line code."** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud . The "baud" term should be used only for communication that POSSIBLY INCLUDES MODULATION (e.g. sending more than ONE bit per communication cycle).

Comment: Interesting...  is this left-over from RS-232 interfacing with modems? Where the "300 baud" was really referring to the analog-side of the modem, and just "accidentally" leaked into the base-band RS-232 comms too? Given that its in such common usage for TTL UARTs, I'm not sure that "baud" is strictly limited to modulated signals??

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should use 'baud' and not 'baud rate', 'baud-rate' or 'baudrate'. Baud is defined by the ITU as the 'unit of modulation rate; the number of bauds is equal to the reciprocal of the duration in seconds of the shortest signal element or of the unit interval in such signal'. Refer to 'ITU-T Recommendation R.140'. For example, if the duration of the unit interval is 20 ms, the modulation rate is 50 bauds. But in practice, almost everyone appends 'rate'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cambridge dictionary's [entry](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/word-formation/compounds) on compound words seems to suggest that *baudrate* would be the preferred spelling.

*Baud* and *rate* are both nouns, in case of noun + noun compounds the words are written without a space (with a bunch of exceptions which don't apply here).

As opposed to for example Dutch or German, many compound words in English *are* written with a space or hyphen between the words. I can imagine a lot of people don't even realize or think about the difference in the case of noun + noun compound words.

<sub>Note: I am not a native English speaker and haven't studied English at a university level.</sub>

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Your grasp of English appears to be very good.